# android- asynctask return error on posting data

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i've an asynctask , I use it for posting some data to a page this is the code :

```
           String responseBody="";
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.108/mySite/getEditProfile.php");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(20000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);


            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("name",  name.getText().toString())
                    .appendQueryParameter("famil", famil.getText().toString())
                    .appendQueryParameter("email", email.getText().toString())

            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();
            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                    responseBody+=line;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v("this",e.getMessage());
        }
        return responseBody;
```

when it comes to it , I get this error :
length=0; index=4

I don't get it, what is this error ? How can I solve this ?

Comment: At which line getting issue?

Comment: I have noticed a blank space on ur url after http://192.168.1.108/mySite

Comment: @RishadAppat thanks for reply , it was a typing mistake but in my code there is no space ,

Comment: post your logcat output....